# How does jQuery mobile work in jsfiddle.net?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsfiddle

I have [this simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/wvVmT/), which uses jQuery mobile, but it's not working.

Q: What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Manage Resources you need to add the jQM css file as well:

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css

Optionally you can also add the jQM framework as well, but I see that jsFiddle is adding this as an option now

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/wvVmT/2/

Comment: Thanks Phill!  I thought I had tried that, but apparently I wasn't using the right css file or something.  But thanks!