# angularjs select ng-options, can not select right option when load

Tags: angularjs

js:

```
    $scope.tasks = [{ Name: "Deliverable", Id: "Deliverable" },
                    { Name: "Email", Id: "Email" }]
    $scope.currentTask = {Subject: "Deliverable"}
```

html:

```
<select ng-model="currentTask.Subject" ng-options="task.Id as task.Name for task in tasks"></select>
```

**result**: 
No option is selected when page load. But the dropdown works well. Am I missing anything?
[image]

Comment: sorry but it is working for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/246/

Comment: ...............I don't know why...

Comment: create a fiddle with your code...it will be better to debug...

Comment: i found the reason, it is because of the jquery mobile js!!!!!!!

Comment: @Srinath hi, how to add a jquery mobile js in your jsfiddle demo? can you add it and let's test again?

Comment: hii..well better follow this question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045893/how-does-jquery-mobile-work-in-jsfiddle-net..