# jquery mobile not displaying in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsfiddle

I can't get a select menu to work in a jquery mobile app, and thought I'd post the problem here, but I can't even get the thing to display properly in fiddle. Thought I'd solve the fiddle problem first.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/steveo_88/e5z0q99p/), which contains the following code:

html

```
<div data-role='content'>
<table class='my-tables'>
    <caption style='text-align: left;'>Table A</caption>
    <thead>
        <TR>
            <TH align='left'>Type</TH>
            <TH align='left'>Amount</TH>
            <th colspan='4' scope='col'>
                <label for='selmenu'></label>
                <select id='selmenu' class='sel' data-native-menu='false' style='width: 100px'>
                    <option class='type1' value='type1'>type1</option>
                    <option class='type2' value='type2'>type2</option>
                    <option class='type3' value='type3'>type3</option>
                    <option class='type4' value='type4'>type4</option>
                </select>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TH align=l eft>Cars</TH>
            <TD>5,000</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type1'>7000</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type2'>6000</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type3'>5000</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type4'>4000</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TH align=l eft>Trucks</TH>
            <TD>45672</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type1'>154</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type2'>1.1</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type3'>3.7</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type4'>55.2</TD>
        </TR>
        <TH align=l eft>Motorcycles</TH>
        <TD>224455</TD>
        <TD class='exhaust type1'>88</TD>
        <TD class='exhaust type2'>99</TD>
        <TD class='exhaust type3'>77</TD>
        <TD class='exhaust type4'>55</TD>
        </TR>
</TABLE>
<div data-role='footer'>
     <h4>my footer</h4>

</div>
<!-- /footer -->
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.exhaust').hide();
$('.type1').show();

$('.sel').change(function () {
    $('.exhaust').hide();
    $('.' + this.value).show();
    $('.sel').val(this.value);
});
});
```

Why won't my fiddle even display the jqm styles? I researched similar problems in stackoverflow, found [this question on the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045893/how-does-jquery-mobile-work-in-jsfiddle-net), but my fiddle page doesn't show the options that are available in the example given in that question.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Use jQuery 1.8.3 library. Included external resource JQM 1.2.0 will not work with later versions.
2. Load external resources with HTTPS:

   https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css
   https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

After that, your fiddle should work.

**UPDATE:**

Besides all above, once you choose jQuery 1.8.3 version, fiddle will offer you JQM library below the framework selection menu. So, no need for including external files.

Comment: okay, that worked -- many thanks! It was not at all obvious that 1.8.3 would offer those options -- would've taken lots more time for me to figure it out. thanks so much